# Divergence and Curl of the vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

How to find the divergence and the curl of the given vectors?

a. $( \vec{u} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{v}$

b. $( \vec{u} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{r}$

c. $( \vec{u} \times \vec{r})$

d. $ \vec{r} \times(\vec{u} \times \vec{r})$

e. $ \psi (r) (\vec{u} \times \vec{r})$

where $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are the constant vectors, $\vec{r}$ is the radius vector and $\psi(r)$ is a scalar function of the magnitude r of the $\vec{r}$

Thanks.

Comment: you list a bunch of problems then expect an answer? your rep seems above putting such questions like this here? don't take it in a slight, but then I didnt want to put "welcome to MSE, blah blah...." either.

Comment: @Chinny84 Well.. i did tried something.. I got $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$ for question a and I wasn't sure if it were correct. And i didn't expect answers i was just hoping for some hints. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: There are references for vector identities that can facilitate.  Without use of these identities, one can still pursue by "brute force."

Comment: @Dr.MV Could you tell me more about "brute force"?? please...

Comment: Sure.  One can apply directly the divergence and curl operators to the given expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example.

Using the product rule for differentiation on Part e, we have

$$\nabla \cdot (\psi(\vec r)(\vec u \times \vec r))=(\vec u \times \vec r)\cdot \nabla \psi(\vec r)+\psi(\vec r)\nabla \cdot (\vec u \times \vec r)$$

The first term can be expressed alternatively as

$$(\vec u \times \vec r)\cdot \nabla \psi(\vec r)=\vec u\cdot (\vec r \times \nabla \psi(\vec r))$$

For the divergence component of the second term, we have (using summation notation)

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot (\vec u \times \vec r)&=\partial_i \hat x_i \cdot (u_j \hat x_j \times x_k\hat x_k)\\\\
&=u_j  \hat x_i \cdot ( \hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\partial_i (x_k)\\\\
&=u_j  \hat x_i \cdot ( \hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\delta_{ik} \\\\
&=u_j  \hat x_i \cdot ( \hat x_j \times \hat x_i)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\nabla \cdot (\psi(\vec r)(\vec u \times \vec r))=\vec u\cdot (\vec r \times \nabla \psi(\vec r))$$